# Are we to avoid listing specific apps / malware?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are we supposed to avoid mentioning a specific piece of malware?  In my latest question, I mentioned a specific piece of malware / app I encountered. The question does have broad applicability as well.  Someone edited my question to remove all the places I mention the specific piece of malware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually going to put it back in. I removed the name because you said in your earlier version that you thought it was malicious and you wanted us to review it. The question could have stood more generically on its own without naming it.

But now that the question is more generic, and the point is that the app is deceptive, the name becomes relevant.

So, in general, naming specific apps should only be done if the name is specifically relevant. If the app is malicious, let's not point people to it. If not relevant, let's not advertise it.